# Favorites count is incorrect in the navigation bar on the profile page

Tags: bug, profile-page, bookmarks, tooltips

I have only favorite one MSE but the navigation bar on MSE displays `14` favorites.  `14` is actually the number of upvotes on the post in question.

[image]

The tooltip when hovering over *favorites* reads **questions you have favorited**.

Could we have the count please instead of the votes?

In case, the count is intended to reflect the *number of activities* that happened on the favorited questions, then the tooltip needs to be fixed.

Comment: I'm getting zero.

Comment: That 14 on the tab bar is actually the number of Things That Have Happened™ (edits, answers, other stuff that bumps a post) to all your favourites since you last looked at that tab.

Comment: @michaelb958 Hmmm.. number of _Things That Have Happened_ seems to be a rather odd count to display.  Isn't it?

Comment: @devnull It's a notification-like thing. It's like the Reputation tab displaying Rep Changes That Have Happened™ since you last looked, or Responses showing you Responses That Have Happened™.